# Qt C++ Gantt Chart not Updating When Adding Data

Tags: c++, qt, gantt-chart

I have a gantt chart, using KDGantt, that is not updating when the user clicks a few buttons and hits the submit button. The GUI initializes with an empty gantt chart as intended, but after clicking the button in the other tab where the user makes the selections and clicks the button, the gantt chart doesn't show anything, even though the QStandardItemModel isn't empty.

I'm using a signal/slot to send the data from the class that allows to the user to make the selections and click submit to the class that contains the gantt chart.

Any help would be appreciated.

The Gantt Chart Class

```
ScheduleAdvice::ScheduleAdvice(QString title, QMainWindow *parent) : QDockWidget(title, parent)
{
    ScheduleInput *sendData = new ScheduleInput();
    setObjectName(title);
    mspInstance = this;

    //Set Schedular tab panel.
    setFeatures( QDockWidget::DockWidgetMovable|QDockWidget::DockWidgetFloatable);
    setFocusPolicy(Qt::StrongFocus);

    QPalette backgroundColor(palette());
    backgroundColor.setColor(QPalette::Background, Qt::black);

    QGridLayout *pGrid = new QGridLayout;
    QWidget *pBaseWidget = new QWidget;

    pBaseWidget->setAutoFillBackground(true);
    pBaseWidget->setPalette(backgroundColor);

    pBaseWidget->setMaximumWidth(800);
    pBaseWidget->setMaximumHeight(2000);

    pBaseWidget->setLayout(pGrid);
    setWidget(pBaseWidget);

    mpModel = new QStandardItemModel;

    connect(sendData, SIGNAL(transferDataSignal(QJsonDocument)), this, SLOT(dataTransferSlot(QJsonDocument)));

    QString scheduleName;
    for(int index = 0; index < mTxArray.size(); ++index){
        int i = rand()%mTxArray.size();
        int j = rand()%mRxArray.size();

        QString iString = QString::number(mTxArray.at(i).toInt());
        QString jString = QString::number(mRxArray.at(j).toInt());
        scheduleName = iString + "+" + jString;

        mpItem = new QStandardItem(QString(scheduleName));
        mpItem->appendRow(QList<QStandardItem*>()
                          << new MyStandardItem(QString(scheduleName))
                          << new MyStandardItem(KDGantt::TypeTask)
                          << new MyStandardItem(QDateTime(QDate(2021, 10, 10), QTime(00, 00, 00)), KDGantt::StartTimeRole)
                          << new MyStandardItem(QDateTime(QDate(2021, 10, 10), QTime(12, 00, 00)), KDGantt::EndTimeRole)
                          );

        mpModel->appendRow(QList<QStandardItem*>()
                           << mpItem
                           << new MyStandardItem(KDGantt::TypeMulti)
                           );
    }

    // Set widget to fit docker widget appropriately.
    KDGantt::View *view = new KDGantt::View();

    // Define graph header to a 24hour period
    KDGantt::DateTimeGrid *grid = new KDGantt::DateTimeGrid;

    grid->setUserDefinedUpperScale(new KDGantt::DateTimeScaleFormatter(KDGantt::DateTimeScaleFormatter::Hour,
                                   QString("hh"),
                                   Qt::AlignLeft));

    // "Removes" the lower header column of the graph.
    grid->setUserDefinedLowerScale(new KDGantt::DateTimeScaleFormatter(KDGantt::DateTimeScaleFormatter::Hour,
                                   QString()));

    //Set bar graph to display 24hour periods
    grid->setScale(KDGantt::DateTimeGrid::ScaleUserDefined);
    grid->setDayWidth(500);
    grid->setRowSeparators(true);

    // Have the bars become blue instead of green.
    QBrush myBrush(Qt::blue);
    view->graphicsView()->itemDelegate()->setDefaultBrush(KDGantt::TypeTask,
                                                          myBrush);
    view->setGrid(grid);
    view->setModel(mpModel);

    // Make it so the user can't change the bars' position.
    view->graphicsView()->setReadOnly(true);
    view->graphicsView()->setStyleSheet("background:gray");

    connect(view->graphicsView(), SIGNAL(clicked(QModelIndex)), this, SLOT(onSelected(QModelIndex)));

    view->leftView()->setStyleSheet("background:gray");
    view->leftView()->setMaximumWidth(100);

    pGrid->update();
    pGrid->addWidget(view, 0, 0, 1, 2);
    pGrid->addWidget(mpDateTimeGroup(), 1, 0, 1, 2);
    pGrid->addWidget(mpRxTableGroup(), 2, 1, 1, 1);
    pGrid->addWidget(mpTxTableGroup(), 2, 0, 1, 1);

}
```

```
Slot Function

void ScheduleAdvice::dataTransferSlot(QJsonDocument doc){
    if(doc.isEmpty()){
        std::cout << "Received empty document." << endl;
    } else {
        mObject = doc.object();

        setGanttModel(mObject);
    }
}

void ScheduleAdvice::setGanttModel(QJsonObject object){
    mTxArray = object["txIds"].toArray();
    mRxArray = object["rxIds"].toArray();
}
```

Comment: In order to change what a view is showing, you'll have to interact with the view object and/or its current model; the view should automatically update itself in response. For example, by calling the QStandardItemModel's `appendRow`, `removeRows`, `setItemData`, etc. in your slot functions.